# App Android Studio conexión Bluetooth con dispositivo relay

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

He estado una semana realizando intentos (con desesperación ya) de hacer una app que tiene como objetivo enviar instrucciones a un dispositivo bluetooth para que realice unas determinadas funciones.

El dispositivo es muy parecido a: http://www.diymalls.com/esp32-wifi-bluetooth-relay-module

He intentado buscar el producto que tengo en la oficina, pero no lo he conseguido. Debe estar descatalogado. He supuesto que las características son muy parecidas.

El hecho es que ya existe una app en la empresa que activa el dispositivo, pero es muy compleja, con varias activitys, y es muy complicado aprovechar el código. Me he estado documentando para hacer la app de nuevo, realizando pruebas con sockets, con BLE, con toda la documentación y ejemplos que he encontrado, sin ningún resultado.

Me he descargado proyectos hechos que se conectan con dispositivos bluetooth, pero no sirve. Una app de conexión bluetooth clásica que cuando se intenta conectar, me devuelve error de conexión con ese dispositivo. Por otro lado, he pensado que podría ser porque utilizan un servidor BLE, pero otra app que se llama "BluetoothLeGatt" en GitHub, que es capaz de escanear dispositivos BLE, no me devuelve ninguna lista.

La idea de la app, es que cuando realice un reconocimiento de dispositivos,  se conecte con un dispositivo concreto por dirección MAC. Luego enviar mediante un hilo secundario (thread) haga un write para enviar un comando hexadecimal. Según el comando, abre o cierra la puerta (deja pasar o no la corriente).

Estoy muy desesperado porque mediante sockets, he tenido muchos problemas con los parámetros inStream o outStream que producían muchos errores, y con el UUID. Y no he conseguido solucionarlo, ni com ejemplos, ni nada.

Estoy intentando contactar con alguien que se haya peleado con algo parecido. Porque es muy desgastante y todo esto se me escapa de las manos.

Saludos y gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya he conseguido que funcione. Con la llibrería RxAndroidBle2. Hay un poco de información, pero facilita el trabajo. Mucho más que usar BluetoothLeService. Voy a documentar todo el proceso y luego lo dejaré público aquí.